# Replacing a string with a real number using a variable

Tags: command-line, sed

I can replace a string by a string using `sed`, but how can I replace a string with a number? My code is:

```
while read x 
do
echo $x 
sed 's/xx/$x/g' xy.in > x1
cat > x1 >> x2.dat
done < xyz.dat
```

I want to replace string `xx` in `xy.in` with the number that I read from file `xyz.dat`. But Instead of the number, I am getting blank spaces in `x2.dat`.